# How to update the value of a key for all objects in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have an array of object as follows:

```
[
 { name:"jon", active: false },
 { name:"eve", active: false },
 { name:"adam", active: true }
]
```

What is the best way to change the value of active so that the entire list of objects has active value as false ? 
Also is there a lodash function that can accomplish this ? 
I am using map but is there a faster better way as my array is very large and the operation needs to done several times ?

Comment: What have you tried so far or what research have you done?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an iterator

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that by simply iterating over the list using `forEach` like so:

```
var list = [
  { name:"jon", active: false },
  { name:"eve", active: false },
  { name:"adam", active: true }
]

list.forEach(item => item.active = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var people = [
    { name:"jon", active: false },
    { name:"eve", active: false },
    { name:"adam", active: true }
];

var inactivePeople = people.map(person => {
    person.active = false;
    return person;
});

console.log(inactivePeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop is faster to do this:

```
let array = [
  { name: "jon", active: false },
  { name: "eve", active: false },
  { name: "adam", active: true }
]

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].active = false
}
```

[jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance)

*Lodash* has a `_.map` and a `_.forEach` method, relatively similar in terms of performance.